# Navigation to sub-screen from BottomNavigationBar-sceeen in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I´m currently working on my first simple flutter application and am trying to figure our the best approach to handle the navigation between screens.

**Already Possible:**

- Navigation through screens with `BottomNavigationBar` + `BottomNavigationBarItem`
- Navigation with `Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen4()),);`

**Problem:**

- Having sub-screens in the screens of `BottomNavigationBar`

**Code Example:**

I want to have three main screens `Screen1()`, `Screen2()` and `Screen3()` accessible from the `BottomNavigationBar`. In `Screen1()` there is a button to navigate to another screen, let´s call it `Screen4()`, where the user can choose from a list of items. You can then add all chosen items to a list and navigate back to `Screen1()`.

To achieve this I created the code below. The main `Widget` of the `body` will be changed according to the current index of the selected `BottomNavigationItem`.

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
    Screen3(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Stackoverflow Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Screen1'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            title: Text('Screen2'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            title: Text('Screen3'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is when I navigate within the `Screen1()` - Widget to `Screen4()` by using

```dart
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen4()),);
```

the navigation will happen outside of `MyApp()` and therefore there is no `Scaffold`.

If someone has an example, where this is achieved I´d be very happy.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but hopefully, it can help you.

To achieve this you can use the Offstage widget with a navigator as its child, this way you will have a persistent navigation bar throughout all of your pages.

you can follow this article for more details and how to implement it

https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf

you might need to tweak it a little to match your case.

info about the Offstage widget:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you run a `CupertinoApp` instead of a `MaterialApp`. Use a `CupertinoTabScaffold` instead of `Scaffold`. Add a `CupertinoTabBar` as tabBar and return a `CupertinoTabView` as a tabBuilder

example of tabBuilder

```
  tabBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return CupertinoTabView(
        navigatorKey: firstTabNavKey,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => Screen1(),
```

Have a look at this great short article on how to implement a Tab Bar and also allow for Navigation between screens: [link](https://medium.com/@info_4766/ios-tab-bar-in-flutter-9379cf09df31)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you maybe have a link to a full example of where this is applied in a similar manner?

Comment: I don't have it but have a go and post what you are working on

Comment: I posted a nice link which should resolve, there is an example